# Compare two comma separated lists in C# to get difference

Tags: c#, string, comparison

If I have two strings that are both comma separated values and I know there will only be 1 part missing from one of the strings, how can I retrieve that in C#?

Example:

```
    String 1 = "one,two,four"
    String 2 = "one,two,three,four"
    Result = "three"
```

I've tried using `String.Compare` which returns -1 or 1 so I know they are different, but how do I actually pull the value of the difference?

I'd like to have a 3rd string containing the missing value from String 1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] the question show what you've tried already and what the problem with it are. Hint: [`String.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0) might help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string result = null; 
string[] arr1 = 1.Split(','); //Get the first string into array
string[] arr2 = 2.Split(','); //Get the second string into array

//Compare lengths, if arr1 is bigger call Except on it, else on arr2
//Linq .Except will return elements of array which aren't in the parameter array
if(arr1.Length > arr2.Length 
{ 
    result = String.Join(" ", arr1.Except(arr2).ToArray()); 
} 
else 
{ 
    result = String.Join(" ", arr2.Except(arr1).ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use linq Except both ways and union to get the differences from both.

```
String[] strs1 = "one,two,four".Split(",");
String[] strs2 = "one,two,three,four".Split(",");
var res = strs1.Except(strs2).Union(strs2.Except(strs1));
String result = String.Join(",",res);
```

Comment: This will fail on third line, because `Union()` doesn't return an array.

Comment: Converting to Array uses extra RAM  and CPU. Would've been better to change the declaration.

Comment: Right again. I missed the join with enumerable parameter.

Answer (score -1):

You have to convert the strings to sequences (`IEnumerable<string>`). Once you have that you can use `Except()`. The simplest way to do this is `String.Split()`, though I really *hate* the method... so many edge cases where this can fall down, and performance isn't even very good. Much better to pull in an actual CSV parser. But for brevity on Stack Overflow:

```cs
var string1 = "one,two,four";
var string2 = "one,two,three,four";

var Result = string.Join(",", string2.Split(',').Except(string1.Split(',')));
```

See it work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/l6AkOr

Answer (score -1):

@Olivier Rogier already gave a good answer. Here is some code to understand the concept (his is more efficient).

```
var split1 = String1.Split(",");
var split 2 = String2.Split(",");
var builder = new StringBuilder();
//other ways to do this, but aiming for illustration of the concept
List<string> list1;
List<string> list2;
if(split1.Length > split2) {
list1 = split1.ToArray();
list2 = split2.ToArray();
}
else {
list2 = split1.ToArray();
list1 = split2.ToArray();
}
foreach(var s in list1)
{
    if(!list2.Contains(s))
    {
        if(builder.Length > 0)
        {
            builder.Append(",");
        }
        builder.Append(s);
    }
}
```

This will produce you a list of one or more items (comma separated if 2 or more). I did this freeform, so there might be a typo, so debug.

Once you understand how it works, read the comment @Olivier Rogier made to your post.